# "with" statement in python __exit__

Tags: python

When using a `with` statement without a `as`, does the `__enter__` function never get executed but the `__exit__` method will?

Example:

```
with test:
  test.do_something
```

`test.__exit__()` will be executed at the end of the with clause but `test.__enter__()` won't?

Comment: Why dont' you just try it and see?

Comment: I did I just wanted to confirm that I did not reach the wrong conclusion :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are always* both executed. The only difference is that if you don't use `as`, the return value of the `__enter__` function is discarded. The precise steps are laid out very nicely in the [`with` statement documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with).

```
class T(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print('entering')
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_t, exc_v, trace):
        print('exiting')

with T():
    pass

>>> entering
>>> exiting
```

The only difference is whether you can use the object created or not:

```
with T() as t:
    print(t)

>>> entering
>>> <__main__.T object at 0x00B34810>
>>> exiting
```

Note that the second example also shows *when* `__exit__` is called: specifically, it's called when the loop completes.

---

*The only time they aren't both executed is if `__enter__` throws an exception, in which case the context manager's suite is never reached, and `__exit__` won't be called.